# How to get data of a specific value from firebase realtime data in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

[image]

Taking the above picture into accord. I want to Fetch data according to the email. For instance i want to fetch key and value if value is "abc@gmail,com". how can i do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

queryEqualToValue is changed. By queryEqual

```
ref.child("POSTBY").queryEqual(toValue: regex.encodeEmails(email).observe(.value) { snapshot in
            for child in snapshot.children {

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
    ref.child("POSTBY").queryEqualToValue("abc@gmail.com").observe(.value) { snapshot in
  for child in snapshot.children {
    ...
  }
}
```

ref here is the variable that holds firebase database instance.

Comment: its returnung this Snap (POSTBY) <null>